PowerBI Measure Does not Count Rows Correctly
In PowerBI have two main data tables, Findings and Scans, with three lookup tables for filtering.  Here's the model:

My problem occurs when creating a measure for the title of my Scans table grid like this:
TITLE_SCANS = "Scans (" & COUNTROWS(ALLSELECTED(Scans)) & ")"

This seems to work whenever I filter on Tools.Tool or Teams.TeamName but it doesn't when I filter on ProductsDistinct.ProductName.  The grid actually shows the correct filtered rows but the measure just shows count of the entire table unfiltered.

Then finally, here's showing filtering on Team.TeamName is correctly used by the measure in my title:

So my questions: why would having the many:many slicer not be picked up like the other two filters that are 1:many? I have a hunch that I need to use KEEPFILTERS and maybe CALCULATETABLE (??) but I can't find a clear explanation of how to do this.
Thanks
